# angular material hide placeholder when on focus

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, placeholder

I have this problem with angular material form when I click a field it doesn't hide the placeholder field this is my source HTML of the component what can change to resolve this problem of the placeholder doesn't hide?
I have a problem with import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; in the typescript file the error cannot read tsconfig.app.json but they compile everything all.

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <p>In questa sezione puoi inserire i dati della tua azienda; una volta compilati i campi, premi il bottone
        Continua per passare al prossimo step. In futuro sarà sempre possibile aggiornare tali dati</p>
      <h1>La tua Azienda</h1>
      <hr>
      <p text-align=right>*campi obbligatori</p>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>AGGIUNGI AZIENZA</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        TIPOLOGIA*
        <input matInput placeholder="seleziona tipologia'" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        NOME*
        <input matInput placeholder="inserisci nome azienda" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        STATO*
        <input matInput placeholder="seleziona stato" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        REGIONE*
        <input matInput placeholder="seleziona regione" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        CITTA'*
        <input matInput placeholder="seleziona città'" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        INDIRIZZO*
        <input matInput placeholder="inserisci indirizzo" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        TELEFONO*
        <input matInput placeholder="+00 1234567" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        EMAIL*
        <input matInput placeholder="esempio@mail.it" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Continua</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>INSERISCI PRODOTTI</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        CATEGORIA DI PRODOTTO
        <input matInput placeholder="Seleziona la categoria del tuo prodotto" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        PRODOTTO
        <input matInput placeholder="Seleziona nome del prodotto" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        CODICE
        <input matInput placeholder="Inserisci codice del prodotto" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="ThirdFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="ThirdFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel> CONFIGURAZIONE EVENTI DI PRODUZIONE </ng-template>


      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="PRODOTTO" formControlName="ThirdCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="FASE DI LAVORAZIONE" formControlName="ThirdCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="EVENTO " formControlName="ThirdCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>

    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

I expect that the placeholder hides automatically when on focus by click.

Comment: i resolve add  at <mat-form-field appearance="fill">

Answer (score 0):

With floatLabel(FloatLabelType = 'always' | 'auto'), 'always' can be fixed all the time so it can be managed conditionally with toggle for any of your custom events i.e. focus event.

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always" appearance="outline" [color]="color"></mat-form-field>
```